# How to remove hardcoded get url from angular?

Tags: angular8

I am using the rest api to get the data. For that i am giving the hardcoded url. How to remove this one?

*Here is service.ts :-*

```
getAllEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]>{
        return this._httpService.get("http://localhost:8080/EmpProject/getAllEmployees")
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

I wan to remove this `http://localhost:8080` hardcode value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use environments.

https://angular.io/guide/build

Answer (score 0):

You can use the environment files for this.
For development environment add your URL to the file `environment.ts`. You can find it in `src > environments`.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080' 
};
```

You can use it like this

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';


@Injectable()
export class MyService {  
  
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getData(id: number) {
    let url = environment.baseUrl + '/datas/1';
    return this.httpClient.get<JSON>(url);
  }
}
```

The same thing for production environment, but you need to change the file `environment.prod.ts`